# Binary modification: Bit manipulation vs list operation

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

If I want to modify a binary number in Python, I have two ways to do it.

1. bit manipulation
2. convert binary to list, and modify the list

I thought that with careful implemention, the 1st way is always faster than the 2nd one.... until today.

Consider the following Python code that do similar meanless work in both ways and measure their run time:

```
import time

def test(i):
  num = 2**i
  print("2**{0}".format(i))

  start = time.time()
  for _ in range(10000):
    mask = 1
    copyNum = num
    while copyNum:
      copyNum &= ~mask
      mask <<= 1
  end = time.time()
  print("bit:", end -start)

  start = time.time()
  for _ in range(10000):
    bits = list(bin(num)[2:])
    for i in range(len(bits)):
      bits[i] = '0'
  end = time.time()
  print("list:", end - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  for i in range(100):
    test(i)
```

Here are some parts of the output:

```
2**0
bit: 0.0030112266540527344
list: 0.009064674377441406
2**1
bit: 0.003314495086669922
list: 0.009698867797851562

...

2**6
bit: 0.010007143020629883
list: 0.010907173156738281
2**7
bit: 0.010860681533813477
list: 0.01178431510925293

...

2**50
bit: 0.08656668663024902
list: 0.03987693786621094
2**51
bit: 0.10903549194335938
list: 0.036728620529174805

...

2**98
bit: 0.20895171165466309
list: 0.0722191333770752
2**99
bit: 0.23352742195129395
list: 0.08042550086975098
```

Results clearly show that when binary number is large enough, "list operation" is faster than "bit manipulation".

1. Could anyone help me understand why?
2. should I just use "list operation" for "binary modification" in general?

P.S. I did these tests in Python 3

Comment: Have you considered using `timeit` or a profiler for these tests, rather than `time.time()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have not tried `timeit`. I am not sure if it makes a difference for this case.